# Custom Razor @helpers in MVC5 areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC project which consists of several areas.

I would like to write custom **Razor** `@helper` which would be shared just within views inside specific area.  Common aproach is to write helpers in `.cshtml` files stored in `App_Code` folder in project root, but this makes those helpers accessible from multiple areas.

Is there any way to keep razor `@helper` separated just for one area?

Comment: Don't you want to use EditorTemplates?

Comment: I dont think that this scenario could be solved by editor templates. I need to wrap my partial view content with quite huge portion of code which should be share across multiple partial view.That is why I need helper. Do you think that I can use edit helper for that? Or do you have any other idea?

Comment: Actually i never user @helper since i found Tamplates. But could be that's it's not an option in your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Razor helpers are "public static" methods inside "public static" classes, they are therefore potentially useful for all views, regardless of areas.

Comment: In this case it is really area specific. I cant put them in shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put them.in app code. You can create a class and add your static extension methods. If you want to only see them for certain views, create them in a different namespace and add a using to your view.

Comment: Thanks but this is not realy suitable choice, because I need to use quite a lot of HTML markup mixed with razor code.

Answer (score 0):

A custom helper to work, you must declare at beginning of your view, or you can register in your web.config, inside your views folder. For example:

My custom helper is:

```
namespace MyCustomSystem.Web.Helpers
{
    public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString GroupedActionButtons(this HtmlHelper helper, string controller, long id)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //Do your logic here.

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(stringBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

In your web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>    
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MyCustomSystem.Web" />
        <add namespace="MyCustomSystem.Web.Helpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Doing this, only areas that has the Helper registered, will work, and you not need to declare a `using` in your Views.

Comment: What namespace should I use for that, since the @helper is declared in views?

Comment: The namspace of your static class, that is your Helper logic. I've edited my answer showing the Helper class, and the namespace.

Comment: I dont want to create extension methods for HtmlHelper. I need to write somehing like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor).

Comment: I recommend you to not use this approach, its difficult unit test, and this way you are putting business logic in your views, it is a bad pratice.. You should create your custom Helpers in *.cs files, because you can apply TDD, and still reuse it.

Comment: It is not about the business logic inside helper. It would be more html markup with a few inline razor commands. That is reason why I rather do that in *.cshtml file than in *.cs.

Comment: Ok. I hope i could helped in some way.